# Why does my iOS app crash when receiving a push notification?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

My iOS app is crashing when it receives a push notification message while running. I'm using the sandbox APNS environment, and using Amazon SNS to send the APNS messages.

When debugging, I set a breakpoint on the first line of the following code snippet:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
  NSDictionary *apnsPayload = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:userInfo];
```

When the app receives a push notification, it hits the breakpoint and lets me debug; at this point I can see that `userInfo` is non-nil and contains the expected dictionary.

However, when I step through the code, the app crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` at the very next line—the assignment to `apnsPayload`. It seems like `userInfo` might be getting deallocated prematurely, but I'm not sure why, or more importantly how to change this.

Comment: Have you tried `NSDictionary *apsInfo = [userInfo objectForKey: @"aps"];`? That's how I extract the `aps` dictionary from the userInfo.

Comment: I have; see my comment on the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've still no idea *why* this is happening, but it stops when I `NSLog()` the `userInfo` argument first. Adding the following line as the first line of the function prevents the crash:

```
  NSLog(@"Received APNS with userInfo %@", userInfo);
```

I can then assign using `- [userInfo objectForKey:]` without causing a crash. (To be clear, attempting this same assignment without the prior `NSLog()` results in the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crash.)

Comment: Please append the question to original one by editing, not post it as answer. :)

Comment: What question? I was stating that I'd found a solution. (Admittedly not a great solution, which is why I've not yet accepted any answer; but the code does run.)

Comment: Oh sorry for my misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it makes sense to turn the NSDictionary into another NSDictionary with [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:] ... also NSDictionary can be non-nil but contain 0 key entries (an empty dictionary).

Perhaps you want: NSDictionary *apnsPayload = [userInfo objectForKey: @"alert"]; ?

See: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

Comment: I was doing that, with the same result; the snippet I posted was a vain attempt to be 'safer'. The `userInfo` dictionary I observed when debugging had all the expected data.